# What's the point of judging whether the bluetooth is enabled twice

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

See the below code:

```
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
```

Why? This is actually quite common in MCU programming, but this is java application we are talking about why? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hmmm.. looks more like a copy paste effect ;)

Answer (score 1):

I agree; I can't see any reason why **such** kind of double checking would have any reasonable effect.

It *looks* like bad practice and everybody just copying it without further thinking (maybe maybe there would be some sense if the second check would go **after** the `new Intent` line before calling startActivity ... but as above, no effects besides confusing the reader.

As this code simply runs the same check twice; without any steps in between that could have side effects on the "thing that is checked".